# Run / Execute the Function and then go to Route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

- I created a react app and implemented two routes.
- The Page on '/' shows a welcome message and /pageone shows the other
  page.
- i have button in homepage( "/" ) which is wrapped with link
  to="/pageone".
- I have a function `onClose = () => {this.setState({visible:false,});}` i want it to run first after that only i want to change my route onclicking/

how to achieve this? is there any way to write a function that runs this onClose function and then route to the link?

Comment: Write a function which run on button click, first include the onclose function in it then use react router redirect to change the path

Answer (score 1):

Your query is regarding the callback function, so you can use the callback function in `this.setState` just like this

```
this.setState({
    visible:false 
},() => {
    /// this part will be executed only after the visible is set to false
});
```